# Simple polytope with smooth facets

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes

Let $P$ be a simple $3$-dimensional (and full-dimensional) lattice polytope such that every facet $F$ is a smooth polytope. Is then $P$ itself smooth?

**EDIT:** A full-dimensional lattice polytope $P$ is called smooth if its normal fan $\Sigma_P$ is smooth.

Comment: What is a "smooth polytope"?

Comment: Isn't the tetrahedron with vertices 000, 110, 101, 011 a counterexample?

Comment: @RichardStanley It is, thanks a lot!